# Доступ к serial port из nativescript

Tags: android, node.js, serial, nativescript

Как можно работать на [android](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html) с usb [serial port](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82) из nativescript в anroid?
Я не имею представления как работают с ним на java и не могу найти нечего подобного в api.
Я читал что обычные npm модули не будут работать на nativescript , как тогда вообще можно докопаться до serial port?
Возможно как то через файловую систему можно долезть до serial port?

Comment: не уверен на счёт андроида но в никсах можно достучаться до железа через папку /dev/ а там грубо говоря блочно писать и читать из устройства как из файла

Comment: Возможно Вам поможет эта статья: https://habrahabr.ru/post/163913/ Опишите потом в ответе что получилось :-)

Comment: наверное никак, в принципе можно открыть dev/tty** и писать/читать  туда, но в обычных условиях надо чтобы были права рута, иначе не даст доступа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению похоже что нету вариантов доступа к serial port из [nativescript](https://www.nativescript.org/).
Из подобных кросс платформенных библиотек, получить доступ получилось в [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/), через плагин [cordovarduino](https://github.com/xseignard/cordovarduino) всё работает, не скажу что идеально, но работает, в отличии от [nativescript](https://www.nativescript.org/) в котором как оказалось нету доступа к serial port.

Answer (score 1):

Сам пока не пробовал, но возможно https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-serialport-api/ сможет предоставить доступ к последовательному порту. На сколько я понимаю, суть в том, что девайс будет находиться системой как файл.